# Prime counting function; when is it true that $\pi(n) > \pi(2n) -\pi(n)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\pi$ be the prime counting function.

Under what conditions is it proven true that $\pi(n) > \pi(2n) -\pi(n)$, if at all?

Comment: because $\pi(x) = \frac{x}{\ln x} + o(x)$ it is true for $x$ big enough. so what you need is a constant $|\pi(x) - \frac{x}{\ln x}| < C x$ for $x > N$ and $2\frac{x}{\ln x} -  \frac{2x}{\ln 2x} > 4Cx$ for $x > M$ and check for $n< \max(N,M)$. (not saying there is no much simpler argument)

Comment: Asymptotically it's true since it's equivalent to say $2\pi(n)>\pi(2n)$ and you have $2\pi(n)=2n/\log n (1+o(1))$ and $\pi(2n) = 2n/\log 2n (1+o(1))$...Bertrand's postulate seems useless for this inequality...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities),

$${x\over\ln x-1}\lt\pi(x)\lt{x\over\ln x-1.1}$$

for large $x$, with the lower bound holding for $x\ge5393$ and the upper bound for $x\ge60184$.  Thus the inequality $\pi(2n)\lt2\pi(n)$ holds for $n\ge30092$, since the inequality

$${2n\over\ln(2n)-1.1}\lt{2n\over\ln n-1}$$

holds for *all* $n$ (i.e., since $\ln2\gt0.1$).  Whether the inequality $\pi(2n)\lt2\pi(n)$ fails for any small $n$ can be "easily" checked.

Comment: We need someone to run a computer program and check the small $n$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger, either that or find cruder bounds that still suffice but kick in earlier.

Comment: `Do[If[PrimePi[2 i] - 2 PrimePi[i] >= 0, Print["Fails: i = ", i]];, {i,
   1, 30092}]` . Fails for $i=1,2,4,10$ but none other.

Answer (score 5):

I've written the program Akiva Weinberger suggested above.  This is just a straightforward interpretation of the sieve of Eratosthenes, in R.

```
n = 30092
top = 2*n
isPrime = rep(TRUE, top)
isPrime[1] = FALSE

nextprime = 2
while (nextprime < sqrt(top)){
  isPrime[seq(2*nextprime, floor(top/nextprime)*nextprime, nextprime)] = FALSE
  nextprime = min(which(isPrime[(nextprime+1):top])) + nextprime
}

#isPrime[n] is now TRUE if n is prime and FALSE otherwise

primePi = cumsum(isPrime) #prime counting function, denoted as pi above

f = primePi[seq(2, 2*n, 2)] - 2*primePi[1:n] 

which(f>0)
```

The output is the list `[1]`.  That is, $\pi(2k) > 2\pi(k)$ for $k = 1$ and no other $k <= 30092$.  As Barry Cipra showed above, we can prove the desired inequality for larger values from of $k$ from known bounds.

If we want to consider the possibility that $\pi(2k) = 2\pi(k)$, we can replace the last line with `which(f>=0)`.  The output here is `[1, 2, 4, 10]`.  And in fact we have $2 = \pi(4) = 2 \pi(2), 4 = \pi(8) = 2 \pi(4), 8 = \pi(20) = 2\pi(10)$.