# Is there a proof that $(n-2x)! \times n^{2x-1} > n!$ (where $x$ is a function related to the prime counting function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

Is it possible to prove the following?

Let $\pi$ be the prime counting function and $A(n)=\pi(2n)-\pi(n)$

> $(n-2A(n))! \times n^{2A(n)-1} > n!$

Comment: Since this question have an obvious relation to your other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649065/prime-counting-function-when-is-it-true-that-pin-pi2n-pin, please link to it or merge the two questions. Also, there's a ) missing in the title

Comment: It is false for $n=3,$ because with $A(3)=1$ the LHS is $1\times 3^1=3$ but the RHS is 6.

Comment: If I did not make mistakes the differences LHS-RHS for $n=2\dots $ are
$ 0, -3, 40, -90, -288, -2982, -28032, -8586, \dots$

Comment: So it's not true for all $n$, i wonder if there is a lower bound

Comment: Experimentally is seems correct for $n>48$